# opengl3 20k sprites slow framerate?

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics, go, game-engine

I have successfully made an opengl 3.x animation in golang. However; the frame by frame update is noticeably slow only after 20k textures rendered.  All the sprites do is simply move from the left side of the screen to the right.  Keep in mind they are all on top of each other because i was too lazy to randomize location.

I have an updated PC that can run GTA5 on high settings but cannot display 20k sprites (quads with textures) in opengl3 environment??

I must be doing something wrong here.  Maybe I need to pack all vertices in one VBO instead of a new vbo for each object?  I bindbuffers every object as well.  I'm not really sure what is causing this bottleneck.  Can someone help as i'm not sure where to go from here?

I have attached my code as reference for anyone that can give some tips on speeding up rendering of 20k sprites in opengl3:
http://pastebin.com/SHQtRPn7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at source code, you should use one VBO and combine geometry for all sprites that share a texture and draw them using one draw call.

Comment: how do I apply transformations to each object if everything is in one vbo?  Do i pass a uniform to the vertex shader that contains a matrix?  Or do i update each vertex using the client so the shader gets hold of the already transformed vertex?

Comment: I also feel like the amount of time to transfer a larger VBO to shader would offset smaller transfers to the shader, thus cancelling out any performance benefit?

Comment: If you do it carefully, the data transfer happens in the background while your program is already doing something else.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL calls are expensive. You're doing lots of them ten thousand times in every single frame. Instead you want to do one big draw call if possible. If not, one draw call per textures + program combination.

Instead of passing a matrix as uniform, you can pass a matrix for each object you draw.

This code is not as good as it could be, but it performs orders of magnitude better than yours.

```
func (drawer *SpriteDrawer) Draw(sprites []Sprite) {
    if len(sprites) == 0 {
        return
    }

    drawer.Use()
    drawer.Texture.Bind(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY)

    tmp := drawer.GetTransform().To32()
    drawer.camera_uniform.UniformMatrix2x3f(false, &tmp)

    vertexbuffer := gl.GenBuffer()
    defer vertexbuffer.Delete()
    vertexbuffer.Bind(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER)

    stride := int(unsafe.Sizeof(sprites[0]))

    gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, stride*len(sprites), sprites, gl.STREAM_DRAW)

    var transform1, transform2, texcoords, texlevel gl.AttribLocation
    transform1 = 0
    transform2 = 1
    texcoords = 2
    texlevel = 3

    transform1.AttribPointer(3, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, unsafe.Offsetof(sprites[0].Transform))
    transform2.AttribPointer(3, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, unsafe.Offsetof(sprites[0].Transform)+unsafe.Sizeof(sprites[0].Transform[0])*3)
    texcoords.AttribPointer(4, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, unsafe.Offsetof(sprites[0].TextureLeft))
    texlevel.AttribPointer(1, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, unsafe.Offsetof(sprites[0].Layer))

    transform1.EnableArray()
    transform2.EnableArray()
    texcoords.EnableArray()
    texlevel.EnableArray()

    gl.DrawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, len(sprites))

    transform1.DisableArray()
    transform2.DisableArray()
    texcoords.DisableArray()
    texlevel.DisableArray()
}
```

[library this is from](https://github.com/joonazan/sprite/blob/master/drawer.go)

Answer (score 1):

One problem which I see is that you are creaing a vbo per every frame. Im not sure what you are trying to do. If you are trying to update your vbo, use glBufferSubData() instead. glBufferData() creates a new buffer every time you call it so it will be more expensive than glBufferSubData() for sure. glBufferSubData() just modifies/updates your vbo. This should give your fps a boost.

Comment: so for each of my vbos (uv, color, vertex) i should call glbuffersubdata and only call glbuffer one time before the loop starts? Am I correct?

Comment: yup :). You use glBufferData() to allocate the memory and then if you need to modify it just use glBufferSubData()

Comment: Thanks.  Would this really give me that much of an fps boost... I mean it is lagging only on 20k quads (4 vertices).. With my graphics card/cpu it should be doing hundreds of thousands of vertices each frame?

Comment: Cant say for sure. This is just one thing which adds overhead.

Comment: If you are modifying that vbo just to apply a transformation (translate, rotate, or scale) then you should really just pass a matrix to the shader. I think that will improve fps more than glBufferSubData().

Comment: Can you elaborate on passing a matrix to shader.  Are you saying use one giant vbo or continue using a vbo for each object?  I'm already passing an MVP matrix up to shader just not the transformation matrix itself.

Comment: Passing a transformation has the exact same procedure as passing a MVP matrix :). You add the uniform matrix in the shader, get its location, and simply use glUniformMatrix4fv() to pass it to the shader. This is an amazing tutorial for more information on opengl matrices: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: If you were rendering each texture at a different spot, you would probably need a matrix for every texture or you  would need to generate a matrix for every texture per pass. In your case, you just need 1 matrix since you are rending 20,000 images at the same spot on top of each other.